# RE: Arduino with neo 6m GPS and push button

Tags: c++, arduino, gps, location

I am an aeronautical student, new to the coding environment.
I'm currently working on a GPS neo 6m module with Arduino mega 2560, where I wanted to save the current location upon pressing the push button. Which function is to be used to save the location by pressing the push button.
Here is what I have done so far. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

````
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;
static const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 3; //gps module connections
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;
// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

const int PUSH_BUTTON = 2;

void setup(){
    pinMode(PUSH_BUTTON, INPUT_PULLUP); //push button input
    
    Serial.begin(9600);
    ss.begin(GPSBaud);
} 

void loop(){
  unsigned char i;
  static const double homeLat = 12.334455, homeLon = 05.112233;


  while (ss.available() > 0){
    gps.encode(ss.read());
    if (gps.location.isUpdated()){
      Serial.print("Latitude= "); 
      Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
      Serial.print(" Longitude= "); 
      Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    }

    
    status = digitalRead(PUSH_BUTTON);
    if (status== HIGH){
          *missing code/confused*

    }  
  
    delay(1000);
  }
}```
````

Comment: A pushbutton event happens when there is a status *change*. either from HIGH to LOW or vice versa. Remember the status of the previous loop run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple just store the values in 2 variables.

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    // The TinyGPS++ object
    TinyGPSPlus gps;
    static const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 3; //gps module connections
    static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;
    // The serial connection to the GPS device
    SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);
    
    const int PUSH_BUTTON = 2;
    double save_lat, save_lang;
    void setup(){
        pinMode(PUSH_BUTTON, INPUT_PULLUP); //push button input
        
        Serial.begin(9600);
        ss.begin(GPSBaud);
    } 
    
    void loop(){
      unsigned char i;
      static const double homeLat = 12.334455, homeLon = 05.112233;
    
    
      while (ss.available() > 0){
        gps.encode(ss.read());
        if (gps.location.isUpdated()){
          Serial.print("Latitude= "); 
          Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
          Serial.print(" Longitude= "); 
          Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
        }
    
        
        status = digitalRead(PUSH_BUTTON);
        if (status== HIGH){
 if (gps.location.isUpdated()){
             save_lat = gps.location.lat();
    save_lang = gps.location.lng();
        }  
      }
        delay(1000);
      }
    }
```